# Function with return type and "use" keyword

Tags: php-7

How can you create a function that specifies both the return type *and* the external variables to `use`?

Are the examples below wrong or is it not supported (yet)?

```php
<?php

$arr = ['test' => 'value'];

function test1() use ($arr) : string { // Line 5
    return $arr['test'];
}
function test2() : string use ($arr) {
    return $arr['test'];
}
```

The error is:

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'use' (T_USE), expecting '{' in [PATH]\index.php on line 5

You can [run the code here](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/267db084223c4e67f4d592539e619eb10af9d62b).

Comment: The `use` keyword is for binding calllng-context variables to a *closure*, and functions defined via a function statement aren't closures. So that's simply not going to work because it doesn't make sense. This perhaps prompts the question: why are you trying to do this, ie: what's the end game here? Clarifying that might help come up with an alternative approach. Also... why - in a dynamic loosely-type langauge like PHP - is it important for you to put type checking on a local function?  It's not like it's going to be part of a published API or anything?

Comment: Ah, of course. The `global` keyword would be what I am looking for. I don't think I have ever actually used it before, so it didn't occur to me. As for why: I am maintaining a long list of namespaced utility functions and wanted to make them configurable. Loading an array at the top of the namespace, and giving the functions access to it, is an elegant solution I think. And before anyone mentions helper classes, injecting dependencies, and stuff like that, don't even bother. I am not in need of a sledgehammer. I am looking for a scalpel.

Comment: Well far from being a sledgehammer, I think those suggestions are closer to a scalpel than the teaspoon you seem to be trying to use as one ;-) But to each their own, eh?

Comment: You are assuming that I am working with a framework of some kind, and that changing the entire code-base is something that I have time for. Anyways, I'll muddle through with a spoon.

Comment: Fair enough. But FYI ("he 'splained..." ;-) if you've decided yer code needs some organisation - which you seem to have - then that's when it's time to start thinking about starting to introduce something *already written* to do so. Something like Pimple can be introduced with a coupla lines of code, and can be used *for one thing* to start with. You don't need to rewrite yer whole codebase, but this might be a portent that moving towards using something to organise the code might be long-term beneficial for you sooner rather than later.

Answer (score 3):

As answered by [Adam Cameron](https://stackoverflow.com/users/894061/adam-cameron) in the comments, the problem is that the [`use`](http://php.net/manual/en/functions.anonymous.php#example-160) language construct only applies to [closures](http://php.net/manual/en/functions.anonymous.php), not to all functions. Thus, using it on normal functions makes no sense and is as such not understood by the parser.

When the function in the example code would have been a closure, everything would have worked.

```php
$arr = ['test' => 'value'];

$fn = function() use ($arr) : string {
    return $arr['test'];
};

echo($fn()); // outputs 'value'
```

You can [run the code here](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/59dd253ad21f4392295ea8c2c2770fd673c7c0bd).

Note that your first attempt is correct: first the `use` statement, then the [return type declaration](http://php.net/manual/en/functions.returning-values.php#functions.returning-values.type-declaration). Trying to reverse these two will result in a parse error.